# Multiple Filtering criteria on search result on client side

Tags: jquery, css, filtering

In my project when I search in database against some criteria it provides a result set of about 2000 rows with about 10 columns.

I want to further filter the data against some multiple column.

For an example I want to see some less result on basis of when coumn1=xxx and column2==yyyy and column3=zzzz. it shoudl show about 50 rows.

I've few questions on this:

1. Is there any framework available which can work on client side (like css, jquery etc.) as result of 2000 rows is already available  to client.
2. Or i need to develop it myself perhaps through DB or something else.

Please mind it I am looking for multiple column filtering not single column
regards,
Arun Mahajan

Comment: https://datatables.net/ this could help you again if you want more help you should describe the data return as a json or a csv does are you using jquery or some js framework such as react etc.

Comment: you have to make a filter in your end in Jquery i have made a similar one few days ago .. but you need to provide a valid markup to see how your 2000 rows are structured .. to make a appropiate filter